# Implement SQL function having() in Magento

Tags: sql, function, magento, having

I need a SQL function "having" in Magento. As far as I know, there is no having function.

So I try to implement it in collection class

```
 public function addAttributeHaving($attribute)
 {
      $this->getSelect()->having($attribute); 
      return $this;
 }
```

and when I use this function

```
 $collectionHotel->addAttributeToSort($order, $dir)
                 ->addAttributeHaving('MIN(`apptha_booking_room_types`.`room_price_per_night`) >= '.$lowestprice)
                ->addAttributeHaving('MIN(`apptha_booking_room_types`.`room_price_per_night`) <= '.$highestprice);
```

output query is fine:

```
SELECT 
    `e` . *,
    MIN(`apptha_booking_room_types`.room_price_per_night) AS `lowestprice`,
    IF(at_status.value_id > 0,
        at_status.value,
        at_status_default.value) AS `status`,
    IF(at_apptha_hotel_period_to.value_id > 0,
        at_apptha_hotel_period_to.value,
        at_apptha_hotel_period_to_default.value) AS `apptha_hotel_period_to`,
    `price_index`.`price`,
    `price_index`.`tax_class_id`,
    `price_index`.`final_price`,
    IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL,
        LEAST(price_index.min_price,
                price_index.tier_price),
        price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`,
    `price_index`.`min_price`,
    `price_index`.`max_price`,
    `price_index`.`tier_price`
FROM
    `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
        LEFT JOIN
    `apptha_booking_room_types` ON (apptha_booking_room_types.entity_id = e.entity_id)
        INNER JOIN
    `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status_default` ON (`at_status_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
        AND (`at_status_default`.`attribute_id` = '89')
        AND `at_status_default`.`store_id` = 0
        LEFT JOIN
    `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
        AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '89')
        AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 1)
        INNER JOIN
    `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `at_apptha_hotel_period_to_default` ON (`at_apptha_hotel_period_to_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
        AND (`at_apptha_hotel_period_to_default`.`attribute_id` = '168')
        AND `at_apptha_hotel_period_to_default`.`store_id` = 0
        LEFT JOIN
    `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `at_apptha_hotel_period_to` ON (`at_apptha_hotel_period_to`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
        AND (`at_apptha_hotel_period_to`.`attribute_id` = '168')
        AND (`at_apptha_hotel_period_to`.`store_id` = 1)
        INNER JOIN
    `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id
        AND price_index.website_id = '1'
        AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
WHERE
    (`e`.`type_id` = 'hotel')
        AND (IF(at_status.value_id > 0,
        at_status.value,
        at_status_default.value) = '1')
        AND (IF(at_apptha_hotel_period_to.value_id > 0,
        at_apptha_hotel_period_to.value,
        at_apptha_hotel_period_to_default.value) >= '2012-11-09')
GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id`
HAVING (MIN(`apptha_booking_room_types`.`room_price_per_night`) >= 0)
    AND (MIN(`apptha_booking_room_types`.`room_price_per_night`) <= 999999999)
ORDER BY `lowestprice` asc
```

When I execute this query in MySQL, the output is fine.

But when I try to use

```
 $collectionHotel->load();
```

this error shows up:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   ‘apptha_booking_room_types.room_price_per_night’ in ‘having clause’

I tried everything I could but I can't solve this problem yet. Can anyone help?

Alternatively, are there better ways to implement the having() function?

Answer (score 2):

i believe as this far, this is a bug of magento..
well... my problem solved by using some trick.. but not use this method because magento always say unknown column although the output query is good.

Comment: Hi, I need to add having to my query too, could you post, please, which solution you have found? Thanks.

Comment: hi kostanos, sry i just read your message just now, i found an other way to implement having, easy way, get your collection, and use this function $collection->getSelect()->having($attribute); hope this help...

Answer (score 0):

Try running the sql manually against the db and change this line

```
....
HAVING (MIN(`apptha_booking_room_types`.`room_price_per_night`) >= 0)
   AND (MIN(`apptha_booking_room_types`.`room_price_per_night`) <= 999999999)
```

to

```
.....
HAVING (`lowestprice` >= 0)
   AND (`lowestprice` <= 999999999)
```

If the above code work then try changing this

```
->addAttributeHaving('`lowestprice` >= '.$lowestprice)
->addAttributeHaving('`lowestprice` <= '.$highestprice);
```

Comment: hello .. thankyou for the answer.. 
i have changed the query into
HAVING (`lowestprice` >= 0) AND (`lowestprice` <= 999999999)
the output is good in mysql

but in magento the error is same
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'lowestprice' in 'having clause'

Comment: What sql does it product now?

Comment: the output sql is good, nothings wrong.. when i try to execute the output in mysql, it works..

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write having and order clause

```
$product_log_data = Mage::getModel('customtabs/productlog')->getCollection();
 $product_log_data->getSelect()->having(
            "rowNumber = 1" );
 $product_log_data->getSelect()->order(
            "rowNumber" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a bug in Magento. I had the same issue, and ended up creating a second DB model class, just for retrieving the data for admin area grid display.

In the constructor method of the second Collection.php file I ended up creating a mysql VIEW using a direct DB query, selecting the data (with a group by clause) from the original table to temporary cache the results.

In the construct method:

```
            $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

            $sql = "
                   CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW your_temp_view_name AS
                   SELECT SUM(column_name) as column_name
                   FROM original_table_name
                   WHERE ...
                   GROUP BY customer_id
            ";

            $writeConnection->query($sql);
```

Because the data is already grouped and the aggregating functions have already been executed, you can then just use normal addAttributeToFilter methods to filter the data.

It's a bit hacky, but it worked in this case. Depending on the amount of data and the amount of simultaneous users, it might or might not work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `$countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::HAVING);` means it will reset `HAVING` from your collection. That means it will remove the having clause. And Its not what you want. You may want to add it to the collection (`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php->_getSelectCountSql()` here.)

But the main culprit it the `getSize()` method which exists in `lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php` file.

> I tried almost any solution available on internet but none of them worked for me.

Now i did the below.

```
public function getSize()
{
    if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {
        //$sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
        $sql = $this->getSelect();
        $this->_totalRecords = count($this->getConnection()->fetchAll($sql, $this->_bindParams));
    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);
}
```

Check i am not even using the `getSelectCountSql()`. I am just reading the whole **SQL QUERY** and **fetching all data** and **return the count** of it. That's all.